# Langserver could not import module app.server

Tags: python, dependencies, fastapi, langchain, py-langchain

I am trying to use the tool lanchain and langserver, and create a api from a template.
Steps I took:

1. create server template

```
langchain app new my-app --package rag-conversation
```

2. copy in the code provided in the cmd after the installation is ready

```
@app.get("/")
async def redirect_root_to_docs():
    return RedirectResponse("/docs")

add_routes(app, rag_conversation_chain, path="/rag-conversation")
```

3. cd into my-app folder and run `langchain serve` in the cmd.

After which the server cant seem to start and throws this error

```
INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: 
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [10212] using WatchFiles
ERROR:    Error loading ASGI app. Could not import module "app.server".
```

Does anyone know how to aproach this issue. There is no -v command option so this is all the information I have to go by.

The project structure is the following:

[image: project structure]

this shows that app does contain the server file.

and the server file has the follwing information inside:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse
from langserve import add_routes
from rag_conversation import chain as rag_conversation_chain

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def redirect_root_to_docs():
    return RedirectResponse("/docs")

add_routes(app, rag_conversation_chain, path="/rag-conversation")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn

    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

If you know a solution for this issue please be descriptive, I have found some people encountering something similar a few months ago,https://github.com/langchain-ai/opengpts/issues/61, but there they were talking about some dependency issue and requirements.txt of which I can't even find in my app structure.